# An issue with creating a new repository from terminal/command prompt

Tags: git

As I'm trying to create the repository from the terminal prompt via Git API call. Since not able to create a new repository from the terminal prompt
But I was able to clone and push my repository file.

```
Command Prompt

C:\Users\user>curl -u 'UniqueUserName' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"MyNewRepo"}'
Enter host password for user ''UniqueUserName'':
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.

C:\Users\user>
```

**PowerShell**

```
PS C:\Users\user> curl -u 'UniqueUserName' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"MyNewRepo"}'
Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'u' is ambiguous. Possible matches 
include: -UseBasicParsing -Uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UserAgent.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -u 'UniqueUserName' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name ...
+      ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand


PS C:\Users\user>
```

From **Git Bash Terminal** command hangs.

---

Why Am I getting this below error message from the command prompt

> curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown
>   error (0x80092013) - The revocation function was unable to check
>   revocation because the revocation server was offline.

Comment: You might be interested in the tool called hub

Answer (score 1):

The curl version you're using is using Schannel, the Windows TLS library.  The error message you're getting means that Schannel tried to check whether the server's certificate was revoked (which some TLS libraries do automatically on connect), and the server that provides revocation status (either via a CRL or OCSP) was unavailable.

If you're on a corporate network or in some situation where there's a TLS proxy (including with some antivirus programs), the proxy may be providing a certificate with bad information or may have failed to provide a valid OCSP or CRL URL.  In such a case, you should either try completely uninstalling the antivirus program and trying again, trying again from a different network without the TLS MITM device, or contacting your local network administrator and explaining the situation to them.

If none of those apply to you, then in all likelihood the relevant OCSP server is just down, and you'll be able to connect when things come back up again.  Some servers provide a pre-included cached response for this case by using OCSP stapling, but api.github.com does not.